# RXSwift bind view model data to view controller uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, rx-swift

I am new to RXSwift, please help to find best solution.
I have view model with instance variable:

```
var capturedImageData: Data?
```

I need to unhide UIImageView view and set image after capturedImageData receives data, for example on capture image from camera.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to observe the value of `capturedImageData`

You can create a `behaviorRelay` of `capturedImageData`

Something like

```
var capturedImageData:<Data?> = BehaviorRelay.init(value: nil)
```

And when you get the data, you add do something like this

```
capturedImageData.accept(data)
```

And in your viewController, you subscribe to `capturedImageData`

```
 self.capturedImageData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (data) in
        self.imageView.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
        self.imageView.isHidden = false
  }).disposed(by: bag)
```

Something of this sort.

Haven't tested the code, but you can follow this approach.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I mocked a very simple example.

From your `ViewModel` layer, you can try to keep an Input / Output structu to make it easy to reuse and consume. Here the input would be your `Data` wherever it comes from, and the output `UIImage?`. In short, ViewModel does the logic to transform the data, the View will load only if available.

```swift
struct ViewModel {

    // input
    let loadingImageData: PublishRelay<Data>

    // output
    let showImage: Driver<UIImage?>

    init() {
        let dataRelay = PublishRelay<Data>()

        self.loadingImageData = dataRelay
        self.showImage = dataRelay.map({ UIImage(data: $0) }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
    }

    func loadimage() {
        // your code here to load Data ...
        loadingImageData.accept(imageData)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // bind output viewmodel to UIImageView 
        viewModel.showImage
            .drive(imageView.rx.image)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

You can extend the logic to hide / show element the same way creating Bool events instead.

```swift
struct ViewModel {
    // ...
    let isImageHidden: Driver<Bool>

    init() {
        let dataRelay = PublishRelay<Data>()

        self.loadingImageData = dataRelay
        self.showImage = dataRelay.map({ UIImage(data: $0) }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
        self.isImageHidden = showImage.map({ $0 == nil })
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...

        viewModel.isImageHidden
            .drive(imageView.rx.isHidden)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Driver` to make sure it runs on main thread.